How can we prove that for an arbitrary operator $\hat{f}$ we can find what is called the transposed operator $\tilde{\hat{f}}$?
Context
While studying quantum mechanics using Landau's Course on Theoretical Physics Volume 3 I came across the following. In $\S$3 Operators on Page 11 Landau proposes that,

For an arbitrary operator $\hat{f}$ we can find what is called the transposed operator $\tilde{\hat{f}}$, defined in such a way that
$$
\int\Phi(\widehat{f}\Psi)dq = \int\Psi(\widetilde{\widehat{f}}\Phi)dq .
$$

The result of this proposition comes up several times in Landau's work and thus a proof or demonstration might be of interest to a wide range of users. For example it comes up when dealing with the multiplication of operators and when differentiating operators with respect to time. Since it comes up again and again, it seems to me that a proof of the proposition is in order; Otherwise, again in my opinion, we are sweeping under the rug something foundational.
Question
How do can we prove this proposition?

Cross-posted by OP on math.SE

The notation is old and cumbersome, but here goes:
Let the un-normalised state, ket vector, $\chi=\hat g\,\Phi$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
       \int\Psi\hat f\hat g\,\Phi\,\mathrm dq
\tag1&=\int\Psi\hat f        \chi\,\mathrm dq\\
\tag2&=\int\left(\tilde{\hat f}\Psi\right)\chi\,\mathrm dq\\
\tag3&=\int\left(\tilde{\hat f}\Psi\right)\left(\hat g\,\Phi\right)\mathrm dq
\end  {align}$$
The crucial step is in Equation (2) being the definition of the transpose of the operator $\hat f$
This will look a lot more sensible in Dirac notation than this old notation. Also, nobody else uses the tilde for the transpose, and it is not just any transpose, it is the Hermitian conjugate transpose operator. In physics notation, we have converged to using $^\dagger$ symbol for the Hermitian conjugate transpose operator, but it is probably better to use the mathematician's notation of $^*$ for it, because then expansion coefficients and states will transform with the same symbols.

That is a totally different and rather fundamental question in quantum theory. It is also rather routinely covered. You will need to search for it under the name of Hermitian, not merely transpose.

You should not be writing answers to your own questions. But you should be made aware that the mathematically precise thing you should look for is the Hermitian adjoint, not the transpose.

@MichaelLevy The transpose is a map on the dual space. I can only agree with naturallyInconsistent here: Before you ask such questions, you must define what you mean. And also, don't write an answer of your question in the question body. Instead, write an answer.

Physicists have meanings to everything that we say. When we mentioned Hermitian adjoint, we meant that quantum theory, as currently formalised in the von Neumann scheme using Hilbert spaces and all, requires the use of the mathematical concept of the Hermitian adjoint. That you restrict yourself to the transpose of a linear map is pretty much guaranteed to lead to disaster down the road.

My Answer
What follows is limited in scope in two ways. First, I will only considering here integral operators with kernels that are defined for applications in quantum mechanics (i.e., kernels written in terms of eigenvalues of a physical quantity $f$ and a complete set of eigenfunctions). Second, I will only considering here the case of a discrete set of eigenvalues of a physical quantity $f$.

Proposition[$\widetilde{\widehat{f}\,\,}$: transpose of operator $ \widehat{f}$]
Let $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ be two distinct functions.
For any integral operator $\widehat{f}$ defined by
$$
\left(\widehat{f}\Psi\right)(q) \equiv \int K_{\hat{f}}(q,q')\Psi(q^\prime)\,dq^\prime,
$$
where the kernel is given in terms of a complete orthonormal set of elements $\left\{\Psi_n\right\}$
as
$$
\sum_{n}f_n\,\Psi_n^*(q^\prime)\, \Psi_n (q).
$$
We can find what is called the transposed operator $\widetilde{\widehat{f}\,\,}$, defined by
$$
\left(\widetilde{\widehat{f}\,\,}\Phi\right)(q) \equiv \int K_{\tilde{\hat{f}}}(q,q')\Phi(q^\prime)\,dq^\prime,
$$
with kernel
$$
K_{\tilde{\hat{f}}}(q,q')
\equiv 
 \sum_{n}\sum_{m^\prime}\sum_{m} f_n\,  a^*_{m^\prime,n}  \,a_{m,n}\,\Phi^*_{m^\prime} (q)\,\Phi_m (q^\prime  )  ,
$$
where
$$
a_{m,n}
=
\int 
\Psi_m(q)\,\Phi_n^*(q)\,dq.
$$
Then,
$$
\int\Phi (\widehat{f} \Psi)  dq
= 
\int\Psi (\widetilde{\widehat{f}\,\,} \Phi) dq.
$$

Proof
\begin{align*}
\int\Phi(q) (\widehat{f} \Psi)(q)  dq
&= 
\int\Phi(q) \left( \int K_{\hat{f}}(q,q')\Psi(q^\prime)\,dq^\prime\right)   dq
\\
&= 
\int\Phi(q) \left( \int \left[\sum_{n}f_n\,\Psi_n^*(q^\prime)\, \Psi_n (q)\right]\Psi(q^\prime)\,dq^\prime\right)   dq
\\
&= 
\int\Psi(q^\prime) \left( \int \left[\sum_{n}f_n\,\Psi_n^*(q^\prime)\,\Psi_n (q ) \right]\Phi(q )\,dq\right)   dq^\prime.
\end{align*}
Now, I can write expand $\Psi_n$ in terms of a second complete set of $\left\{ \Phi_m\right\}$ by writing
\begin{align*}
a_{m,n}
=
\int \Psi_n (q )\,\Phi_m^*(q)\,dq.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\int\Phi(q) (\widehat{f} \Psi)(q)  dq
&= 
\int\Psi(q^\prime) \left( \int \left[\sum_{n}f_n\,\left[\sum_{m'} a^*_{m',n}\Phi^*_{m'} (q^\prime ) \right] \left[\sum_{m} a_{m,n}\Phi_m (q ) \right]\right]\Phi(q )\,dq\right)   dq^\prime
\\
&= 
\int\Psi(q^\prime) \left( \int \left[\sum_{n}\sum_{m^\prime}\sum_{m} f_n\,\left[ a^*_{m^\prime,n}  \,a_{m,n}\,\Phi^*_{m^\prime} (q^\prime )\,\Phi_m (q ) \right]\right]\Phi(q )\,dq\right)   dq^\prime
\\
&= 
\int\Psi(q) \left( \int \left[\sum_{n}\sum_{m^\prime}\sum_{m} f_n\,\left[ a^*_{m^\prime,n}  \,a_{m,n}\,\Phi^*_{m^\prime} (q)\,\Phi_m (q^\prime  ) \right]\right]\Phi(q^\prime  )\,dq^\prime \right)   dq .
\end{align*}
Now by defining a new kernel, $K_{\tilde{\hat{f}}}$, given by
$$
K_{\tilde{\hat{f}}}(q,q')
\equiv 
 \sum_{n}\sum_{m^\prime}\sum_{m} f_n\,  a^*_{m^\prime,n}  \,a_{m,n}\,\Phi^*_{m^\prime} (q)\,\Phi_m (q^\prime  )  ,
$$
we have that
\begin{align*}
\int\Psi(q) \left( \int  K_{\tilde{\hat{f}}}(q,q') \Phi(q^\prime  )\,dq^\prime \right)   dq 
&= 
\int\Psi(q) (\widetilde{\widehat{f}\,\,} \Phi)(q)\, dq.
\end{align*}
QED
